# free and htop report totally different numbers

Tags: ubuntu, memory, htop, free

See the following screenshot:

[image: htop vs free]

The "total" amount of memory is reported at 8GB by both `htop` and `free`, but while `free` reports that only 2.7GB is "used", `htop` reports that 7.53GB is used. `free` reports that 5GB is buffers/cache, while `htop` reports this as 100MB.

I think `htop` is correct here, because the system is sluggish and `kswapd0` has high CPU usage.

What is the reason for this mismatch?

Comment: While I'm sure you are torrenting free software, some explanation of your business case for torrents and media server would keep this on Severfault and not Superuser.

Comment: The processes running on my server are irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Classic confusion on cached versus used. `htop` is counting cached as used but `free` is not.  As this is Linux, read `/proc/meminfo` yourself and see how the counters relate to each other.

Edit: you asked specifically about the difference in cached.

free from procps apparently does page cache plus slab reclaimable. From [proc/sysinfo.c](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/proc/sysinfo.c)

```
  kb_main_cached = kb_page_cache + kb_slab_reclaimable;
```

htop is page cache plus slab reclaim minus shared memory. [linux/LinuxProcessList.c](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/master/linux/LinuxProcessList.c)

```
   this->cachedMem = this->cachedMem + sreclaimable - shmem;
```

Honestly, on modern Linux, I would look at `MemAvailable` and some other counters in /proc/meminfo  directly. If I cared about the numbers.

---

Performance tools, while very useful, can be misleading, confusing, and poorly documented. Do not assume different tools calculate a similarly named thing with the same algorithm.

---

Sluggish and slow response times could be anything. Storage IOPS limits or response times, memory page ins from slow storage, high CPU utilization (maybe not at the instant you took this screenshot), slow network, poorly written applications, and so on.

Quantify what is being slow and how much. You have many applications running: μTorrent Server, mysql, mongo, plex, some other containers. Turn on slow query logs. Profile applications. Log every performance metrics you can into a time series database and look at the graphs.

Comment: htop reports buffers/cache as 4M/105M (respectively), while free reports this as 5G. What would be the reason for this particular mismatch?

Comment: They compute it differently. See edit.